# UIImageView's animationImages behavior not as documented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am a little confused about the behavior of `animationImages` in UIImageView. The documentation says:

> Setting this property to a value other than nil hides the image
>   represented by the `image` property.

Yet, if I `initWithImage`, then set `animationImages` property, the image passed to the init call is displayed. When I start animation, it goes through the array as expected, but once animation is done, it reverts back to `image`. Is the documentation inaccurate?

What I want ultimately is for the `UIImageView` to display the first image in the array, then once animation is complete, display the last image in the array. From what I can tell, it seems like I'll need to set `image` manually at the beginning to the first frame, then set it to the last frame right before I start animation?

Answer (score 0):

you can make the start img as the img you want to start with, and when the animation is running you change the uiimage to the last img you want as the last img, so when the animation stops the last img will be showing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the image property to the image you want to see as the first image.  Just before you call startAnimation, change that to be the last image so after the animation stops it rests on the last image:

In my setup:

```
            animatedIV.animationImages = imageArray;
            animatedIV.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
            animatedIV.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

before I start animation:

```
            animatedIV.image = [imageArray lastObject];
            [animatedIV startAnimation];
```